# On "ondrop" event convert word document to text or string using javascript

Tags: javascript, peer

i was trying to send word document from one user to another using peer.js
it is fine working with text file (.txt, text/plain) where ever on word document i'm not getting content.

here is what i did till now

```
box.on('drop', function (e) {
            e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
            var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
            eachActiveConnection(function (c, $c) {
                if (c.label === 'file') {
                    if (file.type == "text/plain") {
                        alert("type : " + file.type + " - sendable");
                        c.send(file);
                    } else {
                        //here i need to convert word document into text/plain or atleast to string and send the file by using // c.send(file)

                    }
```

Comment: please somebody help, i want to get the inner content o the file even it is word document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but AFAIK docx documents follow a standard which is not simple plain text (as RTF is). I'd give a chance to [DOCX.js](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/DOCX.js), which promises to transform docx base64 strings back and forth to HTML.

Comment: i tried, 

var text = convertContent(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]);

it throwing me an error convertcontent is not defined