# HttpPostedFileBase docx to string in C# - MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to check weather HttpPostedFileBase file is docx or not in case if it is docx i need to read inner data  or content and save it into the string variable

Here is my code

```
form action="/Sample/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="photo">Photo:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Upload()
    {

        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"];
        if(file == docx ) {
            //convert inner data to string
        } else {
           // whatever
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ContentType` property of `HttpPostedFileBase` to get MIME type.

```
private const string _docxMime = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"];
    if (postedFile.ContentType.ToLower() == docxMime) {
        // Read docx
    } else {
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); // or something else
    }
}
```

What about reading `.docx` file - you cannot simply read it as a string. You will need to use [Microsoft Office Interop (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx) or [OpenXML (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx). This question [has been already answered at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633615/how-can-i-read-docx-file).

By the way, your method should not be `void` as your are using ASP.NET MVC.
It should be an `ActionResult`.

Comment: thank you.
here i used html form element to send the file to action result and get the content from it by using C#, but can i use JavaScript or jQuery to do it, I'v tried a lot but none were worked please help me

once look at this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181381/on-ondrop-event-convert-word-document-to-text-or-string-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the extension of your file :

```
 string extension = Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[0].FileName).ToLower();

 if (extension == ".docx")
 {
    //do your things
 }
```

For reading inner data of your docx, I think you need to upload it, get the content, and delete the uploaded file.